# full paths of iptables for up/down scripts

Tags: iptables, raspberry-pi, raspbian, openvpn

I am running a client install of openvpn on a raspberry pi with the latest raspbian os. everything is working except my route-up.sh and down.sh scripts. I can run them manually and they work, but the logs show they error out when being run by openvpn.

I have narrowed down the problem to needing full paths everywhere (paths are relative when executing manually, but I've discovered/have been told that they need to be full paths for when openvpn runs the scripts).

The problem is I can't find where iptables are for raspberry pi. I found the following in /sbin/

> iptables -> xtables-multi
>
> iptables-restore -> xtables-multi
>
> iptables-save -> xtables-multi

Which file does route-up.sh append my rules to? When I try to manually open them up to have a look (any of them), it is scrambled like I a missing a font. Any ideas?

FOR REFERENCE: This is my route-up.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 5
sudo ip rule add from 192.168.0.134 table 10
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 table 10
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d mydns.duckdns.org -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d mydns.duckdns.org -j DROP
if ! pgrep -x "deluged" > /dev/null
then
   sudo -u pi deluged
   PID=$!
   sleep 3
   kill -2 $PID 2>/dev/null
fi
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: As per your script errors: Try to remove the `sudo` in the bash script. If openvpn runs as root the script will have root permissions. If openvpn does not run the script as root then move the script to another location that can run as root on boot. Isnt the default rule table location `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`? Dont know what version OS your running, but check the startup services for `iptables-persistent` to locate the rule save location.

Comment: thanks for the comment jc. I checked and on the default installation of raspberry pi (raspbian) there is directory in /etc/ called iptables. I removed the sudo command but they are still not running. I can no longer find errors in the log, but when I check the iptables, there are no rules listed, only after when I run them manually.

Comment: When and where is your script being run? A better (?) way may be to use the `iptables-persistent` way of loading and saving rules. Check out this [info](http://dev-notes.eu/2016/08/persistent-iptables-rules-in-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus/). If you still require a script to run at startup there are a few ways to accomplish: `crontab @reboot` ; `/etc/network/interfaces` `post-up /etc/iptables/script` ; and others.

Comment: thanks for the thoughts. the reason I have them being triggered by the built-in up/down action within openvpn is because I only want the iptable rules to be applied when openvpn connects. it I set the iptables upon boot, then what happens if openvpn fails to connect, then the raspberry pi fails to connect to the internet. additionally, I only want deluge to have access to the internet when and only when openvpn is connected. would iptables-presistent really address this?

Answer (score 0):

In this type of situation, simply run `which iptables` (or `which <command>`) in your interactive shell to find the full path that is called when you run the program in question using your search path. Then just put that path in to your script.

There are arguments against the use of `which` that favor other programs such as `whence` or `locate`. Use whichever of these options you are most comfortable with.

Comment: Thank you for that. Could you expand on it a bit, I'm not quite grasping what you are saying.

Comment: ok I ran the which command and the path it returned was /sbin/iptables as expected. however as my question outlines, when I browse to that location I see that strange notation which I am not aware of where iptables -> xtables-multi. I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: That is symlink notation. You don't need to worry about that as far as your path concerns go.

Comment: ok thanks @John. I went ahead and add /sbin/iptables in front of the 3 iptables rules. Do I need them on all of them (not sure how to apply those to the other rules or if the full path is necessary). after a reboot, I check with "sudo iptables -L" and they don't show even though the VPN is connected. the route-up script is executed upon initial connection correct? after I manually run it, I see my iptables correctly. In the logs, there are no longer errors of the scripts not running.